# keyerror when trying to insert datetime into Postgresql (pg8000)

Tags: python, postgresql, keyerror, pg8000

Im trying to insert a datetime into pgsql with

`f'UPDATE userdata SET claimed = {fclaim} WHERE userid = {user.id}'`

heres how the fclaim variable is made

```
   nextclaim = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
   
   fclaim = nextclaim + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
```

When i try to insert fclaim into postgresql i get the following error

```
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/server/Documents/blutonium/extensions/points.py", line 162, in daily
    isClaimed = blutapi.getclaimed(ctx.author)
  File "/home/server/Documents/blutonium/blutapi.py", line 445, in getclaimed
    db.run(sql)
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 954, in run
    self._run_cursor.execute(sql, params, stream=stream)
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 351, in execute
    self._c.execute_unnamed(self, operation, args)
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 1262, in execute_unnamed
    args = make_args(vals)
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 213, in make_args
    return tuple(vals[p] for p in placeholders)
  File "/home/server/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 213, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(vals[p] for p in placeholders)
KeyError: '37'
```

using python 3.6.11 on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Please show a complete  example of how you pass the values in. Also it it generally not a good idea to format the string yourself(SQL injection issues).  You should use the parameter passing shown [format](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#basic-example-1) or [numeric](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#numeric-parameter-style). Or one of the others listed  here [dbapi](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) under ```paramstyle```

Answer (score 1):

Following [the docs](https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000#basic-example), here's an example of doing an `UPDATE` with pg8000:

```
conn.run(
    "UPDATE userdata SET claimed = :fclaim WHERE userid = :user_id", fclaim=fclaim,
    user_id=user.id)
```